# Pandas method to format numeric entries only, of a column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a built-in pandas method that can format the numeric entries of a column but not the string entries of the same column? (The latter to be kept unchanged and not made NaN). My existing solution below uses np.vectorize since I could not find such a pandas function. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pth2 = 'y test result.csv'
ffmt1 = '{:.6f}'


def cond_fmt(val1):
    try:
        float(val1)
        return ffmt1.format(val1)  # also catches int & scientific
    except ValueError:
        return val1  # return the string unchanged


df1 = pd.DataFrame([['aa', 9.0],
                    ['bb', 1.3e-5],
                    ['bb', 3],
                    ['cc', '0.00013aa'],
                    ['dd', 0.25]],
                   columns=['name1', 'value1'])
print('\n')
print(df1)
'''
  name1     value1
0    aa          9
1    bb    1.3e-05
2    bb          3
3    cc  0.00013aa
4    dd       0.25
'''

# make strings before writing to disk
df1['value1'] = np.vectorize(cond_fmt)(df1['value1'])
print('\n')
print(df1)
'''
  name1     value1
0    aa   9.000000
1    bb   0.000013
2    bb   3.000000
3    cc  0.00013aa
4    dd   0.250000
'''

df1.to_csv(path_or_buf=pth2, header=True, index=False) 
'''
name1,value1
aa,9.000000
bb,0.000013
bb,3.000000
cc,0.00013aa
dd,0.250000
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you seek (format as a number, except if it's not a number, then keep it as a string) is not a very common operation. It has a strange mix of strings and strings of numbers as an output, thus you will likely not find a built-in pandas method to do this.

Writing custom code for custom requirements is perfectly fine. Your code is elegant enough, it is self-documenting the intended behavior.

Comment: Thanks I agree! This was for somebody else, my own work won't have such unusual examples.